# How to find the music folder directory using C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I made a script which checks a special dir for music and records the song names in a text file. But my problem is that I have to give the dir manually. Is there a way in C# to find the Music folder on windows automatically?

Comment: Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic and Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic See MSDN first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Deleted the "artificial intelligence" tag because nothing in this question is actually about AI

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 10):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic));
```